# Java issue driving me crazy

Tags: java

I get this error when I try to open an specific .jnlp file:

```
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. The application has not been initialized, for more information execute javaws from the command line.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:813)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:532)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:936)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$SecurityDelegateImpl.getClassLoaderSecurity(JNLPClassLoader.java:2393)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.setSecurity(JNLPClassLoader.java:321)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeResources(JNLPClassLoader.java:734)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:285)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.createInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:357)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:429)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:403)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:805)
    ... 2 more
```

that file is for access to Cisco ASA's ASDM and it had been working fine since always, untill yesterday... I'm using 4 more files like that one (cause I have 5 ASA's) and those are working great.

Can anybody helpme please?? Thanks in advance.

BR.

---

thanks to you too @ryekayo, here's what I get from the command line:

```
gaspar@gaspar-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK ~ $ javaws https://192.168.0.5/admin/public/asdm.jnlp
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: NewSize (1536k) is greater than the MaxNewSize (1024k). A new max generation size of 1536k will be used.
netx: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. (Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.)
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. The application has not been initialized, for more information execute javaws from the command line.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:813)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:532)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:936)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$SecurityDelegateImpl.getClassLoaderSecurity(JNLPClassLoader.java:2393)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.setSecurity(JNLPClassLoader.java:321)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeResources(JNLPClassLoader.java:734)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:285)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.createInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:357)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:429)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:403)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:805)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Have you tried running javaws from the command line? This can provide more info as stated by your stacktrace.

Comment: Probably, there was a java upgrade and the new runtime is no more compatible with this version.

Comment: Also, the error message is pointing you at the problem:  Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.

Comment: Also check for the Java control panel (javacpl.exe) but when I had the issue in the past, it was linked to a updated and more restrictive Java runtime

Comment: thanks @DevOps, but if there was a java update, why are the other 4 files working fine?? besides, I can see the message is pointing to the error but how can I fix that??? and for the last, I'm working in Linux, so how can I call the Java Control Panel???

Comment: Use the editing tools to add information to your post and to format it to be more readable.

Comment: @gasparmenendez mostly other are working because they are either using other (jar) files which are signed and allowed `Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed`. On their do not perform operation with special privilege requiring a signed jar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copied this from an iDrac solution that I used to fix my Cisco ASDM issue and found that it worked.

```
https://velenux.wordpress.com/2017/06/07/workaround-for-javaws-jnpl-error-cannot-grant-permissions-to-unsigned-jars/
```

You are getting an error like:

```
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars.
```

Quick workaround:

Find the java.security file. In my case it is located in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/java.security`

Then find the row:

```
jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024
```

Comment it out, copy it, delete the MD5 string.

```
#jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024
jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024
```

Save the file. Try again. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Download a previous version of Java runtime (like 1.7 or 1.6) and run it with this one. Location is at the bottom on the page at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

As state on the page :

> WARNING: These older versions of the JRE and JDK are provided to help developers debug issues in older systems. They are not updated with the latest security patches and are not recommended for use in production.

In our case, you don't have any choice as Cisco is not providing updated signed jar to access your Cisco ASA.

To run it with old version, don't forget to provide full path like for windows

```
c:\tools\jdk1.6.0_95\bin\javaw.exe https://192.168.0.5/admin/public/asdm.jnlp
```

or linux in your case

```
/opt/jdk1.6.0_67/bin/javaws https://192.168.0.5/admin/public/asdm.jnlp
```

Comment: I'm a little bit disoriented here because I don't know java very much...the java's version I have installed is:              **gaspar@gaspar-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK / $ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)** and in the link you sent me I can't find 1.6 or 1.7, from where can I download any of those versions??

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ffa2cz then http://prntscr.com/ffa2hg then http://prntscr.com/ffa2sf

Comment: sorry @DevOps, I already download and installed jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin, but when I run the command I get the following: **gaspar@gaspar-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK ~ $ /opt/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javaws https://192.168.0.5/admin/public/asdm.jnlp
bash: /opt/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javaws: No existe el archivo o el directorio**... what I'm missing here??

Comment: if you try `ls -la /opt/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/` what is the output ? This is to ensure it is available with right permissions.

Comment: **gaspar@gaspar-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK ~ $ ls -la /opt/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/
ls: no se puede acceder a '/opt/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/': No existe el archivo o el directorio**.... sorry, mi Linux is in Spanish, output says something like: directory doesn't exist

Comment: So if directory doesn't exist, either this Java is not installed here, or not installed at all. When you have installed jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin, where did it installed it ? Could it be a permission issue at `/opt`or `/opt/jdk1.6.0_45` or `/opt/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/` preventing your user **gaspar** to access it ?

Comment: We did it my friend @DevOps!! was a path problem.... Thank you very much!!

Comment: After it worked fine for about a month, now it doesn't anymore...I was using jdk1.6.0_45 and now downloaded jdk1.7.0_80 but it's the same. I get "Aplication Error" and a red circle with a white exclamation mark inside...can anybody help me please???